# Python: Shouldn't these two pieces of code produce exactly the same result?

Tags: python

I am trying to retrieve all the files from all the subfolders etc from a certain directory. For this purpose I have used two pieces of code which should be doing exactly the same thing but the results are different. I am using Jupyter Notebook.

```
timestamps = []
for folder_path in folders:
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        for name in files:
            timestamps.append(os.path.join(path, name))
```

and

```
timestamps = []
for folder_path in folders:
    temp = [os.path.join(path, name) for name in files for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(folder_path)]
        timestamps += temp
```

The second piece of code retrieves more files and also sometimes produces the following error:

```
NameError: name 'files' is not defined
```

Is this error associated with Jupyter?
Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For python nested list comprehensions, the outer loop goes first, so your code should actually be:

```py
[os.path.join(path, name) for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(folder_path) for name in files]
```